# Как работает @media?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Допустим если я задаю:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
   свойства
}
```

То почему эти свойства могут применятся для телефона с разрешением 1920х1080?

Дело в viewport'e? Учитывается диагональ?

Comment: А где у вас селектор то ?). Как вы потом это применяете к нужному блоку?

Comment: @Geyan, у меня нормально все работает в примере на codepen. В чем проблема заключается? В каком браузере проверял? Выражения в примере на codepen отличаются от того, что в вопросе. И да, я перепутал с автором вопроса

Comment: @Geyan Не совсем понял вашего примера

Comment: @A.Gusev, Добавь конкретный пример css. А так же модель телефона, и версию его браузера

Comment: @A.Gusev  смотря о каком устройстве идёт речь , к примеру если говорить о яблочных устройствах то у них всё через Ж.. и там вообще проблема в плотности пикселей и все размеры умножают на 2, если о других устройствах   то вот эта статья очень полезная : https://habrahabr.ru/company/google/blog/173861/

Comment: в хроме посмотрите в обще этот css примирился к вашему блоку или нет, возможно другой css код его перебил ну или еще что нибудь. А так вопрос ставить бесполезно.

Comment: @Geyan Спасибо, сейчас почитаю. 
Вопрос в том что на устройстве может быть ширина 1080, но применяются медиа в которых указана совершенно другая ширина. Может быть это дело в визуальном вьюпорте. Как он определяется.

Comment: @A.Gusev  вот от гуру CSS3 на эту тему : https://webref.ru/css/value/media

Answer (score 1):

Данный `@media` элемент будет применен для любой ширины в браузере, напимер если на десктопе уменьшить до 480 пикселей, то буднт применен данный стиль, так что дело обстоит только в ширине браузера

Comment: Да, но вопрос в том, почему браузер говорит что ширина 480px, если ширина экрана устройства 920px